# Java HashMap: How to modify the output of the matrix?

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

A .txt file. Use the below java code to read the file and use a 2-D array (one dimension for the users and other dimension for the products) to store the order#. Also, use a dictionary to map each users to its corresponding array row. How to replace the missing value with 0 in the 2D array?

Users, Products, order#:

```
name1   p1  5 
name1   p2   
name1   p3  2 
name2   p1  3 
name2   p2  1 
name2   p3  
name3   p1  5
name3   p2  
name3   p3  2
name4   p1  3
name4   p2  1
name4   p3
```

The solutions below is worked. But with missing value, the 2D array will have different lengths of column. How to replace the missing value with 0 to generate a matrix with fixed on column?

```
output:
  5 0 2
  3 1 0
  5 0 2
  3 1 0



Map<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>> orderInfo = new LinkedHashMap<>();

while (userScanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = userScanner.nextLine();
     // To-Do : check regx
    String[] columns = line.split("\\t");

    String userId = columns[0];
    String productId = columns[1];
    int order = Integer.parseInt(columns[2]);
    LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> prodMap = orderInfo.get(userId);
    if (prodMap == null || prodMap.isEmpty()) {
        prodMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
    }
    prodMap.put(productId, new Integer(order));
    orderInfo.put(userId, prodMap);
}

int[][] matrix =  new int[orderInfo.size()][];
int row = 0 ;

// dictionary will contain Name as a key and belonging row as a value 
Map<String,Integer> dictionary = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

for (Entry<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>> entry : orderInfo.entrySet())
{
    dictionary.put(entry.getKey(), row);
    matrix[row] = new int[entry.getValue().size()];
    int columns = 0;
    for(Entry<String, Integer> ent : entry.getValue().entrySet())  
    {
        matrix[row][columns] = ent.getValue();
        columns = columns + 1;
    }
    row = row + 1;
}

for (int rw = 0; rw < matrix.length; rw++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < matrix[rw].length; col++) {
        System.out.print(matrix[rw][col]+"    ");
    }
    System.out.println();
 }

System.out.println(dictionary);
```

The above code only can produce a matrix like:

```
5 2
3 1
5 2
3 1
```

Comment: Does `int order = Integer.parseInt(columns[2]);` not throw you a NumberFormatException? If it doesn't, what's the value of `order` then?

Comment: If I replace the missing value with 0, it does not throw NumberFormatException. However, the .txt file contains missing value. My question is how to replace the missing value with 0 when read data from the .txt file? Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused. You said it's not throwing exceptions if you replace the missing column with numbers (0). But in OP you said the code is worked (working). So is your coding working with missing numbers and producing the 5-by-2 matrix you gave?

Comment: When I test the code, I manually input the 0 in place of missing value. At this circumstance the code is working. When I use the actual .txt file which has missing value, the code throw exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it will stop at an array-index-out-of-bound-exception, the simple solution is to check if `columns.length == 3`. If yes, then parse the int; else assign `order` to 0.

```
int order;
if (columns.length == 3)
    order = Integer.parseInt(columns[2]);
else 
    order = 0;
```